# Can for /f tokenize each letter?

Tags: windows, command-line

```
for /f %f in ("abc") do echo %f %g %h
```

is there any way to get f=a  g=b  h=c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows `cmd.exe` – no.

Consider a more capable programming language, such as PowerShell, Perl, or Python.

(FWIW, most Windows systems come with C# and VB.NET compilers hidden deep inside `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET`, if you want something that wouldn't need to be installed manually.)